# What is the behavior of the variables here, i.e. closure. The output is undefined which I don't understand

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

What is the behavior of the variables here, i.e. closure. The output is "undefined" which I don't understand.

```
var x = 21; 
var test = function () { 
    console.log(x); // output: undefined 
    var x = 20; 
}; 
test();
```

Comment: Variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the function but variable initializations aren't hoisted: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting: _"Only declarations are hoisted

JavaScript only hoists declarations, not initializations. If a variable is used in code and then declared and initialized, the value when it is used will be its default initialization (undefined for a variable declared using var, otherwise uninitialized)."_

Comment: `test` actually looks like this: `function() { var x; console.log(x); x = 20; }`

Comment: If you would use `let` (`var` is really just a legacy now with `let` and `const`) you would get `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'x' before initialization`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript creates a global execution context initially and a new execution context every time a function is pushed on the call stack. This happens in two phases: it first creates a variable environment where every variable is stored in a key, value pair of variable_name: undefined (whereas the functions are stored with the function definitions). It then starts executing the code line by line.

If I were to walk through this example:
Global execution context:
Variable Environment {
x: undefined,
test: function definition for test
}

Then the code is executed line by line and 21 replaces undefined for the value of x. Now test is called, so a new execution context is created

Test's execution context:
{
x: undefined
}

Now, when it starts executing the code, it looks for x within this execution context and sees the value is undefined, and logs it.
If x wasn't present in test, it would have looked at the function's parent's execution context, which happens to be the global execution context, and would have logged 21.

Read up on execution context: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-execution-context/
Then read up on lexical scope to understand this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript engine will explain your code like this：

```js
var x = 21; 
var test = function () {
    var x;
    console.log(x); // output: undefined 
    x = 20; 
}; 
test();
```

Answer (score -2):

You forget to put parameter in function test
the code should be like this:-

```
var x = 21; 
var test = function (x) { //here u should put parameter "x"
    console.log(x); // The output from calling method
    var x = 20; //last "x"
    //if u want to get the value of last "x" should call 
    console.log(x); // the value of of last "x"
}; 
test(x); //here u should put parameter "x"
```

in code i explain every thing

Notes:-
Variables defined with let cannot be Redeclared.
Variables defined with let must be Declared before use.
Variables defined with let have Block Scope.
Redeclaring a variable with let, in another block, IS allowed
but with var  Not-allowed

Comment: @jfriend00 You are wrong. The ```var``` declaration in the function body doesn't overshadow an argument. It actually does nothing: https://ideone.com/Ege7fu

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.